# Setting custom WCF-binding behaviour via .config file - why doesn't this work?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-behaviour

I am attempting to insert a custom behavior into my service client, following the example [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.beforesendrequest.aspx)

I appear to be following all of the steps, but I am getting a [ConfigurationErrorsException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationerrorsexception.aspx). Is there anyone more experienced than me who can spot what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the entire app.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ClientLoggingEndpointBehaviour">
                    <myLoggerExtension />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <extensions>
            <behaviorExtensions>
                <add name="myLoggerExtension"
                     type="ChatClient.ClientLoggingEndpointBehaviourExtension, ChatClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
            </behaviorExtensions>
        </extensions>
        <bindings>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint
                behaviorConfiguration="ClientLoggingEndpointBehaviour"
                name="ChatRoomClientEndpoint"
                address="http://localhost:8016/ChatRoom"
                binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
                contract="ChatRoomLib.IChatRoom"
                />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Here is the exception message:

> An error occurred creating the
>   configuration section handler for
>   system.serviceModel/behaviors:
>   Extension element 'myLoggerExtension'
>   cannot be added to this element. 
>   Verify that the extension is
>   registered in the extension collection
>   at
>   system.serviceModel/extensions/behaviorExtensions.
>   Parameter name: element (C:\Documents
>   and Settings\Andrew Shepherd\My
>   Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\WcfPractice\ChatClient\bin\Debug\ChatClient.vshost.exe.config
>   line 5)

I know that I've correctly written the reference to the ClientLoggingEndpointBehaviourExtensionobject, because through the debugger I can see it being instantiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I didn't get the assembly qualified name EXACTLY right.
The assembly qualified name was correct enough for the .NET framework to load, but then the WCF framework performs a naive character-by-character comparison when matching the behavior configurations.

To finally get the exact type name, I wrote code to create an instance of *ClientLoggingEndpointBehaviourExtension* object, and wrote the [AssemblyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx) property to a local variable, which I then copy-and-pasted from the debug window into the .config file.

That I had to do all this is considered to be a bug in the WCF framework. 
(See [this link](https://connect.microsoft.com/wcf/feedback/details/216431/wcf-fails-to-find-custom-behaviorextensionelement-if-type-attribute-doesnt-match-exactly))
Apparently it's fixed in .NET 4.0.

Also see [this article.](http://notgartner.wordpress.com/2006/12/19/rant-an-error-occured-creating-the-configuration-section-handler-for-systemservicemodelbehaviors/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a random thought, but maybe not: reverse the order of the elements in your config so extensions come *before* behaviors.

-Oisin

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable guess, but no, the error is the same.